# What was Data's joke about clowns and Ferengi in gorilla suits?

Tags: star-trek

In [Star Trek: Generations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/?ref_=nv_sr_2), Data remembers a joke and finds it funny. He only reveals the joke's punchline:

> The clown can stay, but the Ferengi in the gorilla suit has to go.

**What was the complete joke?** Is it mentioned anywhere?